# BufferedReader connection doesn't close

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I've created a small scraping class and the method below reads in the text from a page.

However, I've found that the method fails to close the connection properly. This results in a ton of open connections which cause my hosting company to then suspend my account. Is the below correct?

```
private String getPageText(String urlString) {

    String pageText = "";


        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                builder.append(chars, 0, read); 

            pageText = builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "getPageText.MalformedUrlException", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "getPageText.IOException", e);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "getPageText.IOException", e);
                }
        }
        return pageText;


}
```

Comment: You should probably close the URL connection first (i.e., do the opposite of `url.openStream`).

Comment: Do you know how to do that? I can't find it with Autocomplete.

Comment: I think that the answer below (by @epoch) shows how to do it pretty well...

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#close()) reader closes every resource asociated with it. So I think your code is correct.

Comment: @cy3er, the reader is associated with the input stream and not the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just closing the `stream` and not the `connection`, use the following structure:

```
URL u = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)
        u.openConnection();
conn.connect();

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

and then:

```
} finally {
    if (reader != null)
       try {
           reader.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "getPageText.IOException", e);
       }
    }

    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that I have to add a HttpURLConnection and I haven't?

Comment: Dumb question: Can you have a stream but no connection?

Comment: yes, though the connection is still made internally, as the docs state, calling `openStream` is the same as calling `openConnection().getInputStream()`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine in the success case but will potentially leak connections in the failure cases (when the http server returns a 4xx or 5xx status code). In these cases HttpURLConnection provides the response body via `.getErrorStream()` rather than `.getInputStream()` and you should make sure to drain and close that stream as well.

```
URLConnection conn = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
  conn = url.openConnection();
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  // ...
} finally {
  if(reader != null) {
    // ...
  }
  if(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
    InputStream err = ((HttpURLConnection)conn).getErrorStream();
    if(err != null) {
      byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
      while(err.read(buf) >= 0) {}
      err.close();
    }
  }
}
```

There probably needs to be another layer of try/catch inside that finally but you get the idea. You should *not* explicitly `.disconnect()` the connection unless you're sure there won't be any more requests for urls on that host in the near future - `disconnect()` will prevent subsequent requests from being pipelined over the existing connection, which for https in particular will slow things down considerably.